# JavaScript code not working (unable to read input)

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I wrote the following piece of code to read whether the user has entered the login and password fields. However, it is not working. Can someone help me?

```js
function validateForm() 
{
  var x = document.getElementById("login").innerHTML;
  var i;
  for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  {
    if( x.elements[i].value==""|| x.elements[i].value=null)
    {
      alert("Fill in all fields.");
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="login"> 
  <form role="form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-8">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-8" >Login ID:</label>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="Enter login ID">
      </div>

      <label class="control-label col-sm-8" >Password:</label>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-8">         
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
      </div> 

      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `innerHTML` is a _string_ - it doesn’t have an `elements` property that you could loop over.

Comment: You need a list of elements and you use `innerHTML`? - Instead, use `document.querySelector('#login input')`, then you can loop over that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="Enter login ID">
```

To

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" placeholder="Enter login ID">
```

The reason being is because your code

```
document.getElementById("login").value;
```

is looking for a document element with the ID **login** but in your markup the element has the ID **text**, hence your code isn't finding it.

**[Edit]**
As other's have pointed out, you're using `.innerHTML` - this returns the child HTML nodes of the element being selected. Use `.value` instead and check that it isn't an empty string, if it's empty then validation fails.

Comment: I think the OP just doesn't understand what `innerHTML` does and when to use it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Phil . I followed your advice to check the length, but the alert comes irrespective of whether login/password has been entered or not.

Comment: @evolutionxbox this is my first time with javascript so just bear with me.

Comment: @sindhugauri - no problem. I do recommend a quick google of "mdn innerHTML" and reading the article.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some changes in your code.

1. Get all the fields using `document.querySelectorAll("#login input");`
2. Check each of them by `x[i]` (`""` or `null`).

By the way, you can do `for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++)` then you shouldn't define the `i` variable before.

```js
function validateForm() 
{
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("#login input");
  var i;

  for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  {
    if( x[i].value== "" || x[i].value == null)
    {
      alert("Fill in all fields.");
      return false;
    }
  }
  alert('sent');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="login"> 
  <form role="form" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-8">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-8" >Login ID:</label>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="Enter login ID">
      </div>

      <label class="control-label col-sm-8" >Password:</label>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-8">         
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
      </div> 

      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't **add `id="form"`** be **add `id="login"`**

Comment: @evolutionxbox Actually, not need id for the `form` at all. I removed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Get the values of respective input fields and check the length.

See [this code](http://jsbin.com/nifaruneja/edit?html,js,output) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Well, you aren't getting the login form. In your code, instead of getting the login form and iterating its elements, you're getting a undefined element by ID. If you index `.innerHTML` you'll get a error in the browser console because the element doesn't exist. Anyway, you don't want to get the inner HTML of the element because it's a string with the HTML text inside of the element. If you element were valid, then the loop would iterate each character in the inner. Also, it doesn't exist the property `elements` in strings. You're trying to get form elements through a string in the loop block. Here goes a basic example to solve these errors:

Add the following ID to your form:

```
<form id="login" role="form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

And do some changes in the JavaScript code, like:

```
function validateForm() {

    // Get all the text boxes in the form
    var fields = document.getElementById("login").querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");

    // Iterate over the fields
    for(var i = 0, f; f = fields[i]; i++) {

        // Check if the value length is smaller than 1
        if(f.value.length < 1) { // Empty

            alert("Fill in all fields.");

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use event listeners & I would put the error messages under the form fields `<span id="id-error" class="hidden">Error message</span> <span id="pwd-error" class="hidden">Error message</span>` remove the hidden class when they start interacting with the input but the conditions arn't met.

```
function validateForm() {

    function addEvent(obj, type, fn) {
      if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj['e'+type+fn] = fn;
        obj[type+fn] = function(){obj['e'+type+fn]( window.event);}
        obj.attachEvent('on'+type, obj[type+fn]);
      } else
        obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false );
    }

    function validateUserId() {
   if (your validation goes here){
    id-error.classList.remove("hidden");
        return false;
    }else{
        id-error.classList.add("hidden");
        return true;
    }
    }

    function validatePWD() {
    if (your validation goes here){
    pwd-error.classList.remove("hidden");
        return false;
    }else{
        pwd-error.classList.add("hidden");
        return true;
    }
    }

    //variables for input fields & event listeners
    var formUserId = document.getElementById("text");
    var formUserPWD = document.getElementById("pwd");


    //add event handlers
    addEvent(formUserId, 'change', function(event) {
        validateUserId();
    });

    addEvent(formUserId, 'focus', function(event) {
        validateUserId();
    });

    addEvent(formUserId, 'keydown', function(event) {
        validateUserId();
    });

    addEvent(formUserId, 'keyup', function(event) {
        validateUserId();
    });

    addEvent(formUserPWD, 'change', function(event) {
        validatePWD();
    });

    addEvent(formUserPWD, 'focus', function(event) {
        validatePWD();
    });

    addEvent(formUserPWD, 'keydown', function(event) {
        validatePWD();
    });

    addEvent(formUserPWD, 'keyup', function(event) {
        validatePWD();
   }); 
}
```